# Meaning of usage of "Präteritum" in a question

Tags: question, past

In the Question "Hatte Saddam Houssein Massenvernichtungswaffen?" the usage of "Hatte" has me confused, because no time frame is given.

Is the meaning in this case at any point in time? In that case, usually "jemals" is added, because otherwise it feels like it's missing context.

Source of the question:
https://twitter.com/ennolenze/status/1610729010220105732

Comment: To me the time frame is obviously the US invasion of Iraq. I suppose if you never heard of Saddam Hussein before, or the historical and political context of the invasion, the question might be confusing, but I think the person raising the question assumed it would be understood without adding further explanation. I'm not sure what this has to do with German btw, you could ask the same question, with the same answer, about "Did Saddam Hussein have WMD's?"

Comment: Well, no. The person writing the question meant during all the Sadam regime. So the question of what Präteritum implies when used in a question is relevant in this stackexchange...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The präteritum tense in and of itself doesn't imply any specific time frame beyond "in the past". This would have to be established by additional information or context.

Leaving the context of a headline open with the intent of leading the reader into the trap of making a wrong assumption is one of the basic tricks of clickbaiting.